# how to make a buffered reader read from the beginning instead of using another object

Tags: java, bufferedreader

In the below written code, i want the second while loop to read from the second line of the same file which the first while loop is using. As of the now the second while loop is reading from the third line of the file.
I can do it by using another buffered reader. but is there another better way ?

```
filename = data1
readFile = new File(filename);
BufferedReader reader = null;
try
{
    reader = new BufferedReader( new FileReader(readFile) );
}
catch (IOException ioe)
{
    System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());     
}
String newline;
int secondRecord = 0;
while((secondRecord < 2) && ((newline = readline(reader)) != null))
    {
    System.out.println(newline);
            secondRecord ++;
    }

while ((newline = readline(reader)) != null)
    {
    System.out.println(newline);
    }
```

Comment: When you get an exception, it is best not to continue as if it didn't happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BufferedReader supports `mark()` and `reset()`. Thus you should call `mark()` before your first loop, and `reset()` after it, and it then should be able to read the same lines again.

Of course, only do this if the file is not too big, since the BufferedReader has to keep everything in memory to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I would read the file into a List and process the list how you want.

```
List<String> lines = FileUtils.readLines(readFile);
for(String line: lines.subList(0,2))
    System.out.println("first loop "+line);
for(String line: lines.subList(2, lines.size()))
    System.out.println("second loop "+line);
```

Comment: Not advisable on large files!

Comment: @Don, Good point, however given the file has at least 2 lines, it might not be that large. I would consider a 100 MB file to be large and a 1 GB file to be huge.

Answer (score 0):

You can place a [mark](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#mark%28int%29) at the point where you want to return later. (Asuming your use of the file won't require a readahead bufer that is too big.)

Answer (score 0):

I should have used a do while loop instead of the second while.
That way it would read the second line as well.